# CICD and Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, pip

```
FROM odoo:latest
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 --version
RUN python3 -m pip install aliyun-python-sdk-core-v3
```

I have this Dockerfile for CI/CD in Gitlab. I would like to use the upgraded pip to install some packages. However, it doesn't use the upgraded pip but the old version to install the package.

[image: The Result pic]

How can I make it to use the upgraded pip for the package installation?

---

```
+ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/ef/60d7ba03b5c442309ef42e7d69959f73aacccd0d86008362a681c4698e83/pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
Removing intermediate container f5417b04ef8f
 ---> 0af1f9c1c55e
Step 4/8 : RUN python3 -m pip --version
 ---> Running in 04c7a1faac39
+ python3 -m pip --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Removing intermediate container 04c7a1faac39
 ---> 4c9bafd47bce
```

[Cap screen of attempt 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMOkw.png)

I have used the same command but having the same result

Comment: You are already doing it by using `python3 -m pip`. The 1st line upgrades it, and the 3rd line installs the requirements.txt using the same `python3 -m pip` you just upgraded. What is the problem? What is the purpose of the `pip3 --version` check? Maybe it should be `python3 -m pip --version`?

Comment: @GinoMempin because the package that I need to install required the upgraded version of pip, the purpose of the pip3 --version check just I try to ensure it is using the upgraded version for the next step.

Comment: The pip in `python3 -m pip` and in `pip3` seems to be 2 different installations. You are mixing them up. Choose only of them, and use that consistently for all commands.

Comment: @GinoMempin I have tried the same command for both, but it got the same result. also not using the new version of pip

Comment: Can you also post your `FROM` line? For me it says `Requirement already satisfied: pip` when I do `FROM python:3.7`

Comment: The base image would certainly help in reproducing the problem, as @xjcl said. What are the other things you do in the Dockerfile? How is python installed? Do you make modifications to python directories, symlinks, etc. I can't reproduce this on a standard Ubuntu or Python image.

Comment: I have updated the dockerfile details with FROM image and the package I would like to install. It is work on my local docker, but fail when i commit for the cicd process of gitlab

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing how you call pip.

Try either `pip3 install --upgrade pip` or `python3 -m pip --version`.